# Calculate MD5 in C - Display output as string

Tags: hash, hex, md5

So I am trying to create the MD5 hash of an arbitrary string in C using the openssl lib.
This is what I go so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

void compute_md5(char *str, unsigned char digest[16]);

int main()
{
    unsigned char digest[16];
    compute_md5("hello world", digest);
    printf("%s", digest);
    return 0;
}

void compute_md5(char *str, unsigned char digest[16]) {
    MD5_CTX ctx;
    MD5_Init(&ctx);
    MD5_Update(&ctx, str, strlen(str));
    MD5_Final(digest, &ctx);
}
```

However the output is full of unprintable characters. 
How can I properly display it as a hex string?

Comment: Not `printf("%s", digest);`, instead `for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf ("%02x", digest[i]); putchar ('\n');` The output is then `5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it right, you just can't use `printf("%s", digest);` to print `digest` as a string. Note the `unsigned char digest[16];` will be an *array of unsigned char* and will not be *nul-terminated*. You cannot print it as a string. Instead print each element as a hexadecimal number with 2 characters, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%02x", digest[i]);
putchar ('\n');
```

Your complete example would then be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>

void compute_md5(char *str, unsigned char digest[16]);

int main()
{
    unsigned char digest[16];
    compute_md5("hello world", digest);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf("%02x", digest[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
    return 0;
}

void compute_md5(char *str, unsigned char digest[16]) {
    MD5_CTX ctx;
    MD5_Init(&ctx);
    MD5_Update(&ctx, str, strlen(str));
    MD5_Final(digest, &ctx);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/md5openssl
5eb63bbbe01eeed093cb22bb8f5acdc3
```

**Creating A String From `digest`**

If you need to create a string from `digest` that you can print with `printf ("%s\n", buf);` then you create a buffer and instead of writing the 2-char hex representation to `stdout`, use `sprintf` to write it to a buffer, nul-terminate the buffer and then print the string. You could do:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char digest[16];
    char buf[sizeof digest * 2 + 1];
    compute_md5("hello world", digest);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 16; i++, j+=2)
        sprintf(buf+j, "%02x", digest[i]);
    buf[sizeof digest * 2] = 0;
    printf ("%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

(output is the same)

Let me know if that isn't what you are looking for.